# How to stop PhpStorm from stripping single quotes from variable names

Tags: phpstorm, eslint, prettier

I am integrating with a third party that wants a variable `'$email'` sent to them, with the single quotes and all. However, when I save my code, it becomes this: `$email`.

I need PhpStorm or Prettier to stop stripping single quotes. I know I've seen a way to do it in some config file, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know what I was wanting is a little strange. I found out it was just prettier formatting my code and I just put a `// prettier-ignore` on the line above the variable name to have it not format that portion of my code